# How to log/get value of nested array

Tags: javascript

I am new in Javascript, I want to log/get the subitem value form nested array

```
const nestedArray = ["item1", ["subitemA", "subitemB", "subitemC"], "item2", "item3", "item4"];
console.log(nestedArray[0]); // I will get "item1" but how to get any one subitem value like "subitemC"
```

Comment: You mean like `nestedArray[1][2]`?

Comment: `nestedArray.item1[i]`

Comment: @heretic, that is array with key value (object), I just want to get without keyvalue array

Comment: There are 4 answers to that question. Look beyond the one with the pretty green checkmark. Warning: you may have to do some thinking for yourself rather than being able to copy and paste the answer!

Comment: what I need is
console.log(nestedArray[0]); give "itme1"

I want a console.log to get "subitemB" only

Comment: Did you try @StardustGogeta's idea?

Comment: @stardust, yes its correct, I think I am so tired and forgot this simple method, Thank you guys!

Comment: `console.log(nestedArray[1][1]);` for *I want a console.log to get "subitemB" only*

Answer (score 0):

This the simple answer which I was searching

```
const nestedArray = ["item1", ["subitemA", "subitemB", "subitemC"], "item2", "item3", "item4"];
    console.log(nestedArray[1][2]); //
```